pgfplots speed up compilation (filtered rows)
I have a csv file with approx 2000 rows and filter 100 rows of the data. However, the compilation time is already approx five seconds. When we filter rows (see below) are there some pertinent settings to speed up the compilation? I already use standalone tikz to only have to compile once, still, I feel there is room for improvement.
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{xstring}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

%Load csv file
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma, header=true]{data.csv}\data

% Plot the rows where the first column contains Exp18
\begin{axis}[]
\addplot[table/x index={1}, 
        table/y index={2},
        x filter/.code={
            \pgfplotstablegetelem{\coordindex}{Experiment}\of{\data}
            \IfStrEq{\pgfplotsretval}{Exp18}
            {}
            {\def\pgfmathresult{}} }] 
        table {\data};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

Here is the file content of data.csv. (I had to delete some rows to input less than 30000 characters.)
# Exp1, Some meta info...,
# Exp2, ...,
# Exp3, ...,
# Exp4, ...,
# Exp5, ...,
# Exp6, ...,
# Exp7, ...,
# Exp8, ...,
# Exp9, ...,
# Exp10, ...,
# Exp11, ...,
# Exp12, ...,
# Exp13, ...,
# Exp14, ...,
# Exp15, ...,
# Exp16, ...,
# Exp17, ...,
# Exp18, ...,

Experiment,X,Y
Exp1,nan,nan
Exp1,nan,nan
Exp1,nan,nan
Exp1,nan,nan
Exp1,nan,nan
Exp1,nan,nan
Exp1,nan,nan
Exp1,nan,nan
Exp1,nan,nan
Exp1,nan,nan
Exp1,nan,nan
Exp1,nan,nan
Exp1,nan,nan
Exp1,nan,nan
Exp1,nan,nan
Exp1,nan,nan
Exp1,nan,nan
Exp1,nan,nan
Exp1,nan,nan
Exp1,nan,nan
Exp1,nan,nan
Exp1,nan,nan
Exp1,nan,nan
Exp1,nan,nan
Exp1,nan,nan
Exp1,nan,nan
Exp1,nan,nan
Exp1,nan,nan
Exp1,nan,nan
Exp1,nan,nan
Exp1,nan,nan
Exp1,nan,nan
Exp1,nan,nan
Exp1,nan,nan
Exp1,nan,nan
Exp1,nan,nan
Exp1,nan,nan
Exp1,nan,nan
Exp1,nan,nan
Exp1,nan,nan
Exp1,nan,nan
Exp1,nan,nan
Exp1,nan,nan
Exp1,nan,nan
Exp1,nan,nan
Exp1,nan,nan
Exp1,nan,nan
Exp1,nan,nan
Exp1,nan,nan
Exp1,nan,nan
Exp1,nan,nan
Exp1,nan,nan
Exp1,nan,nan
Exp1,nan,nan
Exp1,nan,nan
Exp1,nan,nan
Exp1,nan,nan
Exp1,nan,nan
Exp1,nan,nan
Exp1,nan,nan
Exp1,nan,nan
Exp1,nan,nan
Exp1,nan,nan
Exp1,nan,nan
Exp1,nan,nan
Exp1,nan,nan
Exp1,nan,nan
Exp1,nan,nan
Exp1,nan,nan
Exp1,nan,nan
Exp1,nan,nan
Exp1,nan,nan
Exp1,nan,nan
Exp1,nan,nan
Exp1,nan,nan
Exp1,nan,nan
Exp1,nan,nan
Exp1,nan,nan
Exp1,nan,nan
Exp1,nan,nan
Exp1,nan,nan
Exp1,nan,nan
Exp1,nan,nan
Exp1,nan,nan
Exp1,nan,nan
Exp1,nan,nan
Exp1,nan,nan
Exp1,nan,nan
Exp1,nan,nan
Exp1,nan,nan
Exp1,nan,nan
Exp1,nan,nan
Exp1,nan,nan
Exp1,nan,nan
Exp1,nan,nan
Exp1,nan,nan
Exp1,nan,nan
Exp1,nan,nan
Exp1,nan,nan
Exp1,nan,nan
Exp5,nan,nan
Exp5,nan,nan
Exp5,nan,nan
Exp5,nan,nan
Exp5,nan,nan
Exp5,nan,nan
Exp5,nan,nan
Exp5,nan,nan
Exp5,nan,nan
Exp5,nan,nan
Exp5,nan,nan
Exp5,nan,nan
Exp5,nan,nan
Exp5,nan,nan
Exp5,nan,nan
Exp5,nan,nan
Exp5,nan,nan
Exp5,nan,nan
Exp5,nan,nan
Exp5,nan,nan
Exp5,nan,nan
Exp5,nan,nan
Exp5,nan,nan
Exp5,nan,nan
Exp5,nan,nan
Exp5,nan,nan
Exp5,nan,nan
Exp5,nan,nan
Exp5,nan,nan
Exp5,nan,nan
Exp5,nan,nan
Exp5,nan,nan
Exp5,nan,nan
Exp5,nan,nan
Exp5,nan,nan
Exp5,nan,nan
Exp5,nan,nan
Exp5,nan,nan
Exp5,nan,nan
Exp5,nan,nan
Exp5,nan,nan
Exp5,nan,nan
Exp5,nan,nan
Exp5,nan,nan
Exp5,nan,nan
Exp5,nan,nan
Exp5,nan,nan
Exp5,nan,nan
Exp5,nan,nan
Exp5,nan,nan
Exp5,nan,nan
Exp5,nan,nan
Exp5,nan,nan
Exp5,nan,nan
Exp5,nan,nan
Exp5,nan,nan
Exp5,nan,nan
Exp5,nan,nan
Exp5,nan,nan
Exp5,nan,nan
Exp5,nan,nan
Exp5,nan,nan
Exp5,nan,nan
Exp5,nan,nan
Exp5,nan,nan
Exp5,nan,nan
Exp5,nan,nan
Exp5,nan,nan
Exp5,nan,nan
Exp5,nan,nan
Exp5,nan,nan
Exp5,nan,nan
Exp5,nan,nan
Exp5,nan,nan
Exp5,nan,nan
Exp5,nan,nan
Exp5,nan,nan
Exp5,nan,nan
Exp5,nan,nan
Exp5,nan,nan
Exp5,nan,nan
Exp5,nan,nan
Exp5,nan,nan
Exp5,nan,nan
Exp5,nan,nan
Exp5,nan,nan
Exp5,nan,nan
Exp6,nan,nan
Exp6,nan,nan
Exp6,nan,nan
Exp6,nan,nan
Exp6,nan,nan
Exp6,nan,nan
Exp6,nan,nan
Exp6,nan,nan
Exp6,nan,nan
Exp6,nan,nan
Exp6,nan,nan
Exp6,nan,nan
Exp6,nan,nan
Exp6,nan,nan
Exp6,nan,nan
Exp6,nan,nan
Exp6,nan,nan
Exp6,nan,nan
Exp6,nan,nan
Exp6,nan,nan
Exp6,nan,nan
Exp6,nan,nan
Exp6,nan,nan
Exp6,nan,nan
Exp6,nan,nan
Exp6,nan,nan
Exp6,nan,nan
Exp6,nan,nan
Exp6,nan,nan
Exp6,nan,nan
Exp6,nan,nan
Exp6,nan,nan
Exp6,nan,nan
Exp6,nan,nan
Exp6,nan,nan
Exp6,nan,nan
Exp6,nan,nan
Exp6,nan,nan
Exp6,nan,nan
Exp6,nan,nan
Exp6,nan,nan
Exp6,nan,nan
Exp6,nan,nan
Exp6,nan,nan
Exp6,nan,nan
Exp6,nan,nan
Exp6,nan,nan
Exp6,nan,nan
Exp6,nan,nan
Exp6,nan,nan
Exp6,nan,nan
Exp6,nan,nan
Exp6,nan,nan
Exp6,nan,nan
Exp6,nan,nan
Exp6,nan,nan
Exp6,nan,nan
Exp6,nan,nan
Exp6,nan,nan
Exp6,nan,nan
Exp6,nan,nan
Exp6,nan,nan
Exp6,nan,nan
Exp6,nan,nan
Exp6,nan,nan
Exp6,nan,nan
Exp6,nan,nan
Exp6,nan,nan
Exp6,nan,nan
Exp6,nan,nan
Exp6,nan,nan
Exp6,nan,nan
Exp6,nan,nan
Exp6,nan,nan
Exp6,nan,nan
Exp6,nan,nan
Exp6,nan,nan
Exp6,nan,nan
Exp6,nan,nan
Exp6,nan,nan
Exp6,nan,nan
Exp6,nan,nan
Exp6,nan,nan
Exp6,nan,nan
Exp6,nan,nan
Exp6,nan,nan
Exp6,nan,nan
Exp6,nan,nan
Exp6,nan,nan
Exp6,nan,nan
Exp6,nan,nan
Exp6,nan,nan
Exp6,nan,nan
Exp6,nan,nan
Exp6,nan,nan
Exp6,nan,nan
Exp6,nan,nan
Exp6,nan,nan
Exp6,nan,nan
Exp6,nan,nan
Exp7,nan,nan
Exp7,nan,nan
Exp7,nan,nan
Exp7,nan,nan
Exp7,nan,nan
Exp7,nan,nan
Exp7,nan,nan
Exp7,nan,nan
Exp7,nan,nan
Exp7,nan,nan
Exp7,nan,nan
Exp7,nan,nan
Exp7,nan,nan
Exp7,nan,nan
Exp7,nan,nan
Exp7,nan,nan
Exp7,nan,nan
Exp7,nan,nan
Exp7,nan,nan
Exp7,nan,nan
Exp7,nan,nan
Exp7,nan,nan
Exp7,nan,nan
Exp7,nan,nan
Exp7,nan,nan
Exp7,nan,nan
Exp7,nan,nan
Exp7,nan,nan
Exp7,nan,nan
Exp7,nan,nan
Exp7,nan,nan
Exp7,nan,nan
Exp7,nan,nan
Exp7,nan,nan
Exp7,nan,nan
Exp7,nan,nan
Exp7,nan,nan
Exp7,nan,nan
Exp7,nan,nan
Exp7,nan,nan
Exp7,nan,nan
Exp7,nan,nan
Exp7,nan,nan
Exp7,nan,nan
Exp7,nan,nan
Exp7,nan,nan
Exp7,nan,nan
Exp7,nan,nan
Exp7,nan,nan
Exp7,nan,nan
Exp7,nan,nan
Exp7,nan,nan
Exp7,nan,nan
Exp7,nan,nan
Exp7,nan,nan
Exp7,nan,nan
Exp7,nan,nan
Exp7,nan,nan
Exp7,nan,nan
Exp7,nan,nan
Exp7,nan,nan
Exp7,nan,nan
Exp7,nan,nan
Exp7,nan,nan
Exp7,nan,nan
Exp7,nan,nan
Exp7,nan,nan
Exp7,nan,nan
Exp7,nan,nan
Exp7,nan,nan
Exp7,nan,nan
Exp7,nan,nan
Exp7,nan,nan
Exp7,nan,nan
Exp7,nan,nan
Exp7,nan,nan
Exp7,nan,nan
Exp7,nan,nan
Exp7,nan,nan
Exp7,nan,nan
Exp7,nan,nan
Exp7,nan,nan
Exp7,nan,nan
Exp7,nan,nan
Exp7,nan,nan
Exp7,nan,nan
Exp7,nan,nan
Exp7,nan,nan
Exp7,nan,nan
Exp7,nan,nan
Exp7,nan,nan
Exp7,nan,nan
Exp7,nan,nan
Exp7,nan,nan
Exp7,nan,nan
Exp7,nan,nan
Exp7,nan,nan
Exp7,nan,nan
Exp7,nan,nan
Exp7,nan,nan
Exp8,nan,nan
Exp8,nan,nan
Exp8,nan,nan
Exp8,nan,nan
Exp8,nan,nan
Exp8,nan,nan
Exp8,nan,nan
Exp8,nan,nan
Exp8,nan,nan
Exp8,nan,nan
Exp8,nan,nan
Exp8,nan,nan
Exp8,nan,nan
Exp8,nan,nan
Exp8,nan,nan
Exp8,nan,nan
Exp8,nan,nan
Exp8,nan,nan
Exp8,nan,nan
Exp8,nan,nan
Exp8,nan,nan
Exp8,nan,nan
Exp8,nan,nan
Exp8,nan,nan
Exp8,nan,nan
Exp8,nan,nan
Exp8,nan,nan
Exp8,nan,nan
Exp8,nan,nan
Exp8,nan,nan
Exp8,nan,nan
Exp8,nan,nan
Exp8,nan,nan
Exp8,nan,nan
Exp8,nan,nan
Exp8,nan,nan
Exp8,nan,nan
Exp8,nan,nan
Exp8,nan,nan
Exp8,nan,nan
Exp8,nan,nan
Exp8,nan,nan
Exp8,nan,nan
Exp8,nan,nan
Exp8,nan,nan
Exp8,nan,nan
Exp8,nan,nan
Exp8,nan,nan
Exp8,nan,nan
Exp8,nan,nan
Exp8,nan,nan
Exp8,nan,nan
Exp8,nan,nan
Exp8,nan,nan
Exp8,nan,nan
Exp8,nan,nan
Exp8,nan,nan
Exp8,nan,nan
Exp8,nan,nan
Exp8,nan,nan
Exp8,nan,nan
Exp8,nan,nan
Exp8,nan,nan
Exp8,nan,nan
Exp8,nan,nan
Exp8,nan,nan
Exp8,nan,nan
Exp8,nan,nan
Exp8,nan,nan
Exp8,nan,nan
Exp8,nan,nan
Exp8,nan,nan
Exp8,nan,nan
Exp8,nan,nan
Exp8,nan,nan
Exp8,nan,nan
Exp8,nan,nan
Exp8,nan,nan
Exp8,nan,nan
Exp8,nan,nan
Exp8,nan,nan
Exp8,nan,nan
Exp8,nan,nan
Exp8,nan,nan
Exp8,nan,nan
Exp8,nan,nan
Exp8,nan,nan
Exp8,nan,nan
Exp8,nan,nan
Exp8,nan,nan
Exp8,nan,nan
Exp8,nan,nan
Exp8,nan,nan
Exp8,nan,nan
Exp8,nan,nan
Exp8,nan,nan
Exp8,nan,nan
Exp8,nan,nan
Exp8,nan,nan
Exp8,nan,nan
Exp9,nan,nan
Exp9,nan,nan
Exp9,nan,nan
Exp9,nan,nan
Exp9,nan,nan
Exp9,nan,nan
Exp9,nan,nan
Exp9,nan,nan
Exp9,nan,nan
Exp9,nan,nan
Exp9,nan,nan
Exp9,nan,nan
Exp9,nan,nan
Exp9,nan,nan
Exp9,nan,nan
Exp9,nan,nan
Exp9,nan,nan
Exp9,nan,nan
Exp9,nan,nan
Exp9,nan,nan
Exp9,nan,nan
Exp9,nan,nan
Exp9,nan,nan
Exp9,nan,nan
Exp9,nan,nan
Exp9,nan,nan
Exp9,nan,nan
Exp9,nan,nan
Exp9,nan,nan
Exp9,nan,nan
Exp9,nan,nan
Exp9,nan,nan
Exp9,nan,nan
Exp9,nan,nan
Exp9,nan,nan
Exp9,nan,nan
Exp9,nan,nan
Exp9,nan,nan
Exp9,nan,nan
Exp9,nan,nan
Exp9,nan,nan
Exp9,nan,nan
Exp9,nan,nan
Exp9,nan,nan
Exp9,nan,nan
Exp9,nan,nan
Exp9,nan,nan
Exp9,nan,nan
Exp9,nan,nan
Exp9,nan,nan
Exp9,nan,nan
Exp9,nan,nan
Exp9,nan,nan
Exp9,nan,nan
Exp9,nan,nan
Exp9,nan,nan
Exp9,nan,nan
Exp9,nan,nan
Exp9,nan,nan
Exp9,nan,nan
Exp9,nan,nan
Exp9,nan,nan
Exp9,nan,nan
Exp9,nan,nan
Exp9,nan,nan
Exp9,nan,nan
Exp9,nan,nan
Exp9,nan,nan
Exp9,nan,nan
Exp9,nan,nan
Exp9,nan,nan
Exp9,nan,nan
Exp9,nan,nan
Exp9,nan,nan
Exp9,nan,nan
Exp9,nan,nan
Exp9,nan,nan
Exp9,nan,nan
Exp9,nan,nan
Exp9,nan,nan
Exp9,nan,nan
Exp9,nan,nan
Exp9,nan,nan
Exp9,nan,nan
Exp9,nan,nan
Exp9,nan,nan
Exp9,nan,nan
Exp9,nan,nan
Exp9,nan,nan
Exp9,nan,nan
Exp9,nan,nan
Exp9,nan,nan
Exp9,nan,nan
Exp9,nan,nan
Exp9,nan,nan
Exp9,nan,nan
Exp9,nan,nan
Exp9,nan,nan
Exp9,nan,nan
Exp9,nan,nan
Exp10,nan,nan
Exp10,nan,nan
Exp10,nan,nan
Exp10,nan,nan
Exp10,nan,nan
Exp10,nan,nan
Exp10,nan,nan
Exp10,nan,nan
Exp10,nan,nan
Exp10,nan,nan
Exp10,nan,nan
Exp10,nan,nan
Exp10,nan,nan
Exp10,nan,nan
Exp10,nan,nan
Exp10,nan,nan
Exp10,nan,nan
Exp10,nan,nan
Exp10,nan,nan
Exp10,nan,nan
Exp10,nan,nan
Exp10,nan,nan
Exp10,nan,nan
Exp10,nan,nan
Exp10,nan,nan
Exp10,nan,nan
Exp10,nan,nan
Exp10,nan,nan
Exp10,nan,nan
Exp10,nan,nan
Exp10,nan,nan
Exp10,nan,nan
Exp10,nan,nan
Exp10,nan,nan
Exp10,nan,nan
Exp10,nan,nan
Exp10,nan,nan
Exp10,nan,nan
Exp10,nan,nan
Exp10,nan,nan
Exp10,nan,nan
Exp10,nan,nan
Exp10,nan,nan
Exp10,nan,nan
Exp10,nan,nan
Exp10,nan,nan
Exp10,nan,nan
Exp10,nan,nan
Exp10,nan,nan
Exp10,nan,nan
Exp10,nan,nan
Exp10,nan,nan
Exp10,nan,nan
Exp10,nan,nan
Exp10,nan,nan
Exp10,nan,nan
Exp10,nan,nan
Exp10,nan,nan
Exp10,nan,nan
Exp10,nan,nan
Exp10,nan,nan
Exp10,nan,nan
Exp10,nan,nan
Exp10,nan,nan
Exp10,nan,nan
Exp10,nan,nan
Exp10,nan,nan
Exp10,nan,nan
Exp10,nan,nan
Exp10,nan,nan
Exp10,nan,nan
Exp10,nan,nan
Exp10,nan,nan
Exp10,nan,nan
Exp10,nan,nan
Exp10,nan,nan
Exp10,nan,nan
Exp10,nan,nan
Exp10,nan,nan
Exp10,nan,nan
Exp10,nan,nan
Exp10,nan,nan
Exp10,nan,nan
Exp10,nan,nan
Exp10,nan,nan
Exp10,nan,nan
Exp10,nan,nan
Exp10,nan,nan
Exp10,nan,nan
Exp10,nan,nan
Exp10,nan,nan
Exp10,nan,nan
Exp10,nan,nan
Exp10,nan,nan
Exp10,nan,nan
Exp10,nan,nan
Exp10,nan,nan
Exp10,nan,nan
Exp10,nan,nan
Exp10,nan,nan
Exp11,nan,nan
Exp11,nan,nan
Exp11,nan,nan
Exp11,nan,nan
Exp11,nan,nan
Exp11,nan,nan
Exp11,nan,nan
Exp11,nan,nan
Exp11,nan,nan
Exp11,nan,nan
Exp11,nan,nan
Exp11,nan,nan
Exp11,nan,nan
Exp11,nan,nan
Exp11,nan,nan
Exp11,nan,nan
Exp11,nan,nan
Exp11,nan,nan
Exp11,nan,nan
Exp11,nan,nan
Exp11,nan,nan
Exp11,nan,nan
Exp11,nan,nan
Exp11,nan,nan
Exp11,nan,nan
Exp11,nan,nan
Exp11,nan,nan
Exp11,nan,nan
Exp11,nan,nan
Exp11,nan,nan
Exp11,nan,nan
Exp11,nan,nan
Exp11,nan,nan
Exp11,nan,nan
Exp11,nan,nan
Exp11,nan,nan
Exp11,nan,nan
Exp11,nan,nan
Exp11,nan,nan
Exp11,nan,nan
Exp11,nan,nan
Exp11,nan,nan
Exp11,nan,nan
Exp11,nan,nan
Exp11,nan,nan
Exp11,nan,nan
Exp11,nan,nan
Exp11,nan,nan
Exp11,nan,nan
Exp11,nan,nan
Exp11,nan,nan
Exp11,nan,nan
Exp11,nan,nan
Exp11,nan,nan
Exp11,nan,nan
Exp11,nan,nan
Exp11,nan,nan
Exp11,nan,nan
Exp11,nan,nan
Exp11,nan,nan
Exp11,nan,nan
Exp11,nan,nan
Exp11,nan,nan
Exp11,nan,nan
Exp11,nan,nan
Exp11,nan,nan
Exp11,nan,nan
Exp11,nan,nan
Exp11,nan,nan
Exp11,nan,nan
Exp11,nan,nan
Exp11,nan,nan
Exp11,nan,nan
Exp11,nan,nan
Exp11,nan,nan
Exp11,nan,nan
Exp11,nan,nan
Exp11,nan,nan
Exp11,nan,nan
Exp11,nan,nan
Exp11,nan,nan
Exp11,nan,nan
Exp11,nan,nan
Exp11,nan,nan
Exp11,nan,nan
Exp11,nan,nan
Exp11,nan,nan
Exp11,nan,nan
Exp11,nan,nan
Exp11,nan,nan
Exp11,nan,nan
Exp11,nan,nan
Exp11,nan,nan
Exp11,nan,nan
Exp11,nan,nan
Exp11,nan,nan
Exp11,nan,nan
Exp11,nan,nan
Exp11,nan,nan
Exp11,nan,nan
Exp12,nan,nan
Exp12,nan,nan
Exp12,nan,nan
Exp12,nan,nan
Exp12,nan,nan
Exp12,nan,nan
Exp12,nan,nan
Exp12,nan,nan
Exp12,nan,nan
Exp12,nan,nan
Exp12,nan,nan
Exp12,nan,nan
Exp12,nan,nan
Exp12,nan,nan
Exp12,nan,nan
Exp12,nan,nan
Exp12,nan,nan
Exp12,nan,nan
Exp12,nan,nan
Exp12,nan,nan
Exp12,nan,nan
Exp12,nan,nan
Exp12,nan,nan
Exp12,nan,nan
Exp12,nan,nan
Exp12,nan,nan
Exp12,nan,nan
Exp12,nan,nan
Exp12,nan,nan
Exp12,nan,nan
Exp12,nan,nan
Exp12,nan,nan
Exp12,nan,nan
Exp12,nan,nan
Exp12,nan,nan
Exp12,nan,nan
Exp12,nan,nan
Exp12,nan,nan
Exp12,nan,nan
Exp12,nan,nan
Exp12,nan,nan
Exp12,nan,nan
Exp12,nan,nan
Exp12,nan,nan
Exp12,nan,nan
Exp12,nan,nan
Exp12,nan,nan
Exp12,nan,nan
Exp12,nan,nan
Exp12,nan,nan
Exp12,nan,nan
Exp12,nan,nan
Exp12,nan,nan
Exp12,nan,nan
Exp12,nan,nan
Exp12,nan,nan
Exp12,nan,nan
Exp12,nan,nan
Exp12,nan,nan
Exp12,nan,nan
Exp12,nan,nan
Exp12,nan,nan
Exp12,nan,nan
Exp12,nan,nan
Exp12,nan,nan
Exp12,nan,nan
Exp12,nan,nan
Exp12,nan,nan
Exp12,nan,nan
Exp12,nan,nan
Exp12,nan,nan
Exp12,nan,nan
Exp12,nan,nan
Exp12,nan,nan
Exp12,nan,nan
Exp12,nan,nan
Exp12,nan,nan
Exp12,nan,nan
Exp12,nan,nan
Exp12,nan,nan
Exp12,nan,nan
Exp12,nan,nan
Exp12,nan,nan
Exp12,nan,nan
Exp12,nan,nan
Exp12,nan,nan
Exp12,nan,nan
Exp12,nan,nan
Exp12,nan,nan
Exp12,nan,nan
Exp12,nan,nan
Exp12,nan,nan
Exp12,nan,nan
Exp12,nan,nan
Exp12,nan,nan
Exp12,nan,nan
Exp12,nan,nan
Exp12,nan,nan
Exp12,nan,nan
Exp12,nan,nan
Exp13,nan,nan
Exp13,nan,nan
Exp13,nan,nan
Exp13,nan,nan
Exp13,nan,nan
Exp13,nan,nan
Exp13,nan,nan
Exp13,nan,nan
Exp13,nan,nan
Exp13,nan,nan
Exp13,nan,nan
Exp13,nan,nan
Exp13,nan,nan
Exp13,nan,nan
Exp13,nan,nan
Exp13,nan,nan
Exp13,nan,nan
Exp13,nan,nan
Exp13,nan,nan
Exp13,nan,nan
Exp13,nan,nan
Exp13,nan,nan
Exp13,nan,nan
Exp13,nan,nan
Exp13,nan,nan
Exp13,nan,nan
Exp13,nan,nan
Exp13,nan,nan
Exp13,nan,nan
Exp13,nan,nan
Exp13,nan,nan
Exp13,nan,nan
Exp13,nan,nan
Exp13,nan,nan
Exp13,nan,nan
Exp13,nan,nan
Exp13,nan,nan
Exp13,nan,nan
Exp13,nan,nan
Exp13,nan,nan
Exp13,nan,nan
Exp13,nan,nan
Exp13,nan,nan
Exp13,nan,nan
Exp13,nan,nan
Exp13,nan,nan
Exp13,nan,nan
Exp13,nan,nan
Exp13,nan,nan
Exp13,nan,nan
Exp13,nan,nan
Exp13,nan,nan
Exp13,nan,nan
Exp13,nan,nan
Exp13,nan,nan
Exp13,nan,nan
Exp13,nan,nan
Exp13,nan,nan
Exp13,nan,nan
Exp13,nan,nan
Exp13,nan,nan
Exp13,nan,nan
Exp13,nan,nan
Exp13,nan,nan
Exp13,nan,nan
Exp13,nan,nan
Exp13,nan,nan
Exp13,nan,nan
Exp13,nan,nan
Exp13,nan,nan
Exp13,nan,nan
Exp13,nan,nan
Exp13,nan,nan
Exp13,nan,nan
Exp13,nan,nan
Exp13,nan,nan
Exp13,nan,nan
Exp13,nan,nan
Exp13,nan,nan
Exp13,nan,nan
Exp13,nan,nan
Exp13,nan,nan
Exp13,nan,nan
Exp13,nan,nan
Exp13,nan,nan
Exp13,nan,nan
Exp13,nan,nan
Exp13,nan,nan
Exp13,nan,nan
Exp13,nan,nan
Exp13,nan,nan
Exp13,nan,nan
Exp13,nan,nan
Exp13,nan,nan
Exp13,nan,nan
Exp13,nan,nan
Exp13,nan,nan
Exp13,nan,nan
Exp13,nan,nan
Exp13,nan,nan
Exp14,nan,nan
Exp14,nan,nan
Exp14,nan,nan
Exp14,nan,nan
Exp14,nan,nan
Exp14,nan,nan
Exp14,nan,nan
Exp14,nan,nan
Exp14,nan,nan
Exp14,nan,nan
Exp14,nan,nan
Exp14,nan,nan
Exp14,nan,nan
Exp14,nan,nan
Exp14,nan,nan
Exp14,nan,nan
Exp14,nan,nan
Exp14,nan,nan
Exp14,nan,nan
Exp14,nan,nan
Exp14,nan,nan
Exp14,nan,nan
Exp14,nan,nan
Exp14,nan,nan
Exp14,nan,nan
Exp14,nan,nan
Exp14,nan,nan
Exp14,nan,nan
Exp14,nan,nan
Exp14,nan,nan
Exp14,nan,nan
Exp14,nan,nan
Exp14,nan,nan
Exp14,nan,nan
Exp14,nan,nan
Exp14,nan,nan
Exp14,nan,nan
Exp14,nan,nan
Exp14,nan,nan
Exp14,nan,nan
Exp14,nan,nan
Exp14,nan,nan
Exp14,nan,nan
Exp14,nan,nan
Exp14,nan,nan
Exp14,nan,nan
Exp14,nan,nan
Exp14,nan,nan
Exp14,nan,nan
Exp14,nan,nan
Exp14,nan,nan
Exp14,nan,nan
Exp14,nan,nan
Exp14,nan,nan
Exp14,nan,nan
Exp14,nan,nan
Exp14,nan,nan
Exp14,nan,nan
Exp14,nan,nan
Exp14,nan,nan
Exp14,nan,nan
Exp14,nan,nan
Exp14,nan,nan
Exp14,nan,nan
Exp14,nan,nan
Exp14,nan,nan
Exp14,nan,nan
Exp14,nan,nan
Exp14,nan,nan
Exp14,nan,nan
Exp14,nan,nan
Exp14,nan,nan
Exp14,nan,nan
Exp14,nan,nan
Exp14,nan,nan
Exp14,nan,nan
Exp14,nan,nan
Exp14,nan,nan
Exp14,nan,nan
Exp14,nan,nan
Exp14,nan,nan
Exp14,nan,nan
Exp14,nan,nan
Exp14,nan,nan
Exp14,nan,nan
Exp14,nan,nan
Exp14,nan,nan
Exp14,nan,nan
Exp14,nan,nan
Exp14,nan,nan
Exp14,nan,nan
Exp14,nan,nan
Exp14,nan,nan
Exp14,nan,nan
Exp14,nan,nan
Exp14,nan,nan
Exp14,nan,nan
Exp14,nan,nan
Exp14,nan,nan
Exp14,nan,nan
Exp15,nan,nan
Exp15,nan,nan
Exp15,nan,nan
Exp15,nan,nan
Exp15,nan,nan
Exp15,nan,nan
Exp15,nan,nan
Exp15,nan,nan
Exp15,nan,nan
Exp15,nan,nan
Exp15,nan,nan
Exp15,nan,nan
Exp15,nan,nan
Exp15,nan,nan
Exp15,nan,nan
Exp15,nan,nan
Exp15,nan,nan
Exp15,nan,nan
Exp15,nan,nan
Exp15,nan,nan
Exp15,nan,nan
Exp15,nan,nan
Exp15,nan,nan
Exp15,nan,nan
Exp15,nan,nan
Exp15,nan,nan
Exp15,nan,nan
Exp15,nan,nan
Exp15,nan,nan
Exp15,nan,nan
Exp15,nan,nan
Exp15,nan,nan
Exp15,nan,nan
Exp15,nan,nan
Exp15,nan,nan
Exp15,nan,nan
Exp15,nan,nan
Exp15,nan,nan
Exp15,nan,nan
Exp15,nan,nan
Exp15,nan,nan
Exp15,nan,nan
Exp15,nan,nan
Exp15,nan,nan
Exp15,nan,nan
Exp15,nan,nan
Exp15,nan,nan
Exp15,nan,nan
Exp15,nan,nan
Exp15,nan,nan
Exp15,nan,nan
Exp15,nan,nan
Exp15,nan,nan
Exp15,nan,nan
Exp15,nan,nan
Exp15,nan,nan
Exp15,nan,nan
Exp15,nan,nan
Exp15,nan,nan
Exp15,nan,nan
Exp15,nan,nan
Exp15,nan,nan
Exp15,nan,nan
Exp15,nan,nan
Exp15,nan,nan
Exp15,nan,nan
Exp15,nan,nan
Exp15,nan,nan
Exp15,nan,nan
Exp15,nan,nan
Exp15,nan,nan
Exp15,nan,nan
Exp15,nan,nan
Exp15,nan,nan
Exp15,nan,nan
Exp15,nan,nan
Exp15,nan,nan
Exp15,nan,nan
Exp15,nan,nan
Exp15,nan,nan
Exp15,nan,nan
Exp15,nan,nan
Exp15,nan,nan
Exp15,nan,nan
Exp15,nan,nan
Exp15,nan,nan
Exp15,nan,nan
Exp15,nan,nan
Exp15,nan,nan
Exp15,nan,nan
Exp15,nan,nan
Exp15,nan,nan
Exp15,nan,nan
Exp15,nan,nan
Exp15,nan,nan
Exp15,nan,nan
Exp15,nan,nan
Exp15,nan,nan
Exp15,nan,nan
Exp15,nan,nan
Exp16,nan,nan
Exp16,nan,nan
Exp16,nan,nan
Exp16,nan,nan
Exp16,nan,nan
Exp16,nan,nan
Exp16,nan,nan
Exp16,nan,nan
Exp16,nan,nan
Exp16,nan,nan
Exp16,nan,nan
Exp16,nan,nan
Exp16,nan,nan
Exp16,nan,nan
Exp16,nan,nan
Exp16,nan,nan
Exp16,nan,nan
Exp16,nan,nan
Exp16,nan,nan
Exp16,nan,nan
Exp16,nan,nan
Exp16,nan,nan
Exp16,nan,nan
Exp16,nan,nan
Exp16,nan,nan
Exp16,nan,nan
Exp16,nan,nan
Exp16,nan,nan
Exp16,nan,nan
Exp16,nan,nan
Exp16,nan,nan
Exp16,nan,nan
Exp16,nan,nan
Exp16,nan,nan
Exp16,nan,nan
Exp16,nan,nan
Exp16,nan,nan
Exp16,nan,nan
Exp16,nan,nan
Exp16,nan,nan
Exp16,nan,nan
Exp16,nan,nan
Exp16,nan,nan
Exp16,nan,nan
Exp16,nan,nan
Exp16,nan,nan
Exp16,nan,nan
Exp16,nan,nan
Exp16,nan,nan
Exp16,nan,nan
Exp16,nan,nan
Exp16,nan,nan
Exp16,nan,nan
Exp16,nan,nan
Exp16,nan,nan
Exp16,nan,nan
Exp16,nan,nan
Exp16,nan,nan
Exp16,nan,nan
Exp16,nan,nan
Exp16,nan,nan
Exp16,nan,nan
Exp16,nan,nan
Exp16,nan,nan
Exp16,nan,nan
Exp16,nan,nan
Exp16,nan,nan
Exp16,nan,nan
Exp16,nan,nan
Exp16,nan,nan
Exp16,nan,nan
Exp16,nan,nan
Exp16,nan,nan
Exp16,nan,nan
Exp16,nan,nan
Exp16,nan,nan
Exp16,nan,nan
Exp16,nan,nan
Exp16,nan,nan
Exp16,nan,nan
Exp16,nan,nan
Exp16,nan,nan
Exp16,nan,nan
Exp16,nan,nan
Exp16,nan,nan
Exp16,nan,nan
Exp16,nan,nan
Exp16,nan,nan
Exp16,nan,nan
Exp16,nan,nan
Exp16,nan,nan
Exp16,nan,nan
Exp16,nan,nan
Exp16,nan,nan
Exp16,nan,nan
Exp16,nan,nan
Exp16,nan,nan
Exp16,nan,nan
Exp16,nan,nan
Exp16,nan,nan
Exp17,nan,nan
Exp17,nan,nan
Exp17,nan,nan
Exp17,nan,nan
Exp17,nan,nan
Exp17,nan,nan
Exp17,nan,nan
Exp17,nan,nan
Exp17,nan,nan
Exp17,nan,nan
Exp17,nan,nan
Exp17,nan,nan
Exp17,nan,nan
Exp17,nan,nan
Exp17,nan,nan
Exp17,nan,nan
Exp17,nan,nan
Exp17,nan,nan
Exp17,nan,nan
Exp17,nan,nan
Exp17,nan,nan
Exp17,nan,nan
Exp17,nan,nan
Exp17,nan,nan
Exp17,nan,nan
Exp17,nan,nan
Exp17,nan,nan
Exp17,nan,nan
Exp17,nan,nan
Exp17,nan,nan
Exp17,nan,nan
Exp17,nan,nan
Exp17,nan,nan
Exp17,nan,nan
Exp17,nan,nan
Exp17,nan,nan
Exp17,nan,nan
Exp17,nan,nan
Exp17,nan,nan
Exp17,nan,nan
Exp17,nan,nan
Exp17,nan,nan
Exp17,nan,nan
Exp17,nan,nan
Exp17,nan,nan
Exp17,nan,nan
Exp17,nan,nan
Exp17,nan,nan
Exp17,nan,nan
Exp17,nan,nan
Exp17,nan,nan
Exp17,nan,nan
Exp17,nan,nan
Exp17,nan,nan
Exp17,nan,nan
Exp17,nan,nan
Exp17,nan,nan
Exp17,nan,nan
Exp17,nan,nan
Exp17,nan,nan
Exp17,nan,nan
Exp17,nan,nan
Exp17,nan,nan
Exp17,nan,nan
Exp17,nan,nan
Exp17,nan,nan
Exp17,nan,nan
Exp17,nan,nan
Exp17,nan,nan
Exp17,nan,nan
Exp17,nan,nan
Exp17,nan,nan
Exp17,nan,nan
Exp17,nan,nan
Exp17,nan,nan
Exp17,nan,nan
Exp17,nan,nan
Exp17,nan,nan
Exp17,nan,nan
Exp17,nan,nan
Exp17,nan,nan
Exp17,nan,nan
Exp17,nan,nan
Exp17,nan,nan
Exp17,nan,nan
Exp17,nan,nan
Exp17,nan,nan
Exp17,nan,nan
Exp17,nan,nan
Exp17,nan,nan
Exp17,nan,nan
Exp17,nan,nan
Exp17,nan,nan
Exp17,nan,nan
Exp17,nan,nan
Exp17,nan,nan
Exp17,nan,nan
Exp17,nan,nan
Exp17,nan,nan
Exp17,nan,nan
Exp18,nan,nan
Exp18,nan,nan
Exp18,1.758,0.1279
Exp18,2.7777,0.1718
Exp18,3.7679,0.212
Exp18,4.7874,0.2447
Exp18,5.8074,0.2752
Exp18,6.8276,0.2997
Exp18,7.8479,0.3194
Exp18,8.8679,0.3362
Exp18,9.8874,0.3562
Exp18,10.9074,0.3726
Exp18,11.8975,0.3856
Exp18,12.918,0.4001
Exp18,13.9378,0.4135
Exp18,14.9578,0.4284
Exp18,15.9773,0.4392
Exp18,16.9974,0.4492
Exp18,18.0179,0.4578
Exp18,19.0378,0.4685
Exp18,20.0276,0.4834
Exp18,21.0478,0.4923
Exp18,22.0674,0.5009
Exp18,23.0875,0.5102
Exp18,24.1079,0.521
Exp18,25.1276,0.5325
Exp18,26.1479,0.5425
Exp18,27.1377,0.5478
Exp18,28.1574,0.5582
Exp18,29.1775,0.569
Exp18,30.2278,0.579
Exp18,31.2479,0.589
Exp18,32.2672,0.5961
Exp18,33.2874,0.6032
Exp18,34.3079,0.6113
Exp18,35.298,0.6236
Exp18,36.3177,0.6314
Exp18,37.3377,0.6389
Exp18,38.3573,0.6452
Exp18,39.3776,0.6549
Exp18,40.3981,0.6668
Exp18,41.4176,0.6753
Exp18,42.408,0.6809
Exp18,43.4274,0.6894
Exp18,44.4474,0.7017
Exp18,45.4675,0.7117
Exp18,46.488,0.7184
Exp18,47.5079,0.727
Exp18,48.5275,0.7352
Exp18,49.5473,0.7456
Exp18,50.5374,0.7556
Exp18,51.5579,0.7642
Exp18,52.5778,0.772
Exp18,53.5981,0.7846
Exp18,54.6173,0.7958
Exp18,55.6373,0.8051
Exp18,56.6578,0.8125
Exp18,57.6781,0.8214
Exp18,58.6678,0.8356
Exp18,59.6879,0.8467
Exp18,60.7072,0.8549
Exp18,61.7275,0.8623
Exp18,62.7479,0.8724
Exp18,63.7676,0.8861
Exp18,64.7878,0.898
Exp18,65.7776,0.9059
Exp18,66.7974,0.9159
Exp18,67.8175,0.93
Exp18,68.8381,0.9427
Exp18,69.8576,0.9531
Exp18,70.8778,0.9627
Exp18,71.8974,0.9724
Exp18,72.9175,0.9843
Exp18,73.9076,0.9988
Exp18,74.928,1.0089
Exp18,75.9479,1.0185
Exp18,76.9676,1.0319
Exp18,77.9872,1.0464
Exp18,79.0074,1.0591
Exp18,80.0281,1.0717
Exp18,81.0179,1.0821
Exp18,82.0378,1.0974
Exp18,83.0571,1.1122
Exp18,84.0774,1.1253
Exp18,85.0978,1.1364
Exp18,86.1179,1.1502
Exp18,87.1379,1.1658
Exp18,88.1575,1.1833
Exp18,89.1472,1.1933
Exp18,90.1675,1.2074
Exp18,91.188,1.2245
Exp18,92.2077,1.2416
Exp18,93.2279,1.2595
Exp18,94.2472,1.2733
Exp18,95.2675,1.2889
Exp18,96.2881,1.3056
Exp18,97.2781,1.3249
Exp18,98.2974,1.3413
Exp18,99.3177,1.3569
Exp18,100,1.3551 


Preprocess/filter the .csv file with python and generate a .dat file. Then use the simple pgf \addplot [blue] table {data.dat} to input.
Performing the preprocessing in Latex is going to be much slower than a real language like python.
--Randy

My idea is to have a compact file containing all data. Imagine I want to plot e.g Exp14 rows, later Exp2 rows,... I would have to create many .dat files. I agree this is probably the best solution to achieve best compilation times, but maybe there are some improvements for my current setting.

Sorry, I don't have any suggestions on optimizing the pgf code directly.
